# Visual Studio c#, using the .Image property is throwing an error for some reason

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to clear the images from all the picture boxes on a single click.

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
    if (x is PictureBox)
    {
        x.Image = null;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

[image] Thanks for the help.

Comment: For the next time please: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obvious, `Control` class does not have a property with the name `Image`. You need to cast the control to a `PictureBox` object, like this:

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls) // renamed x to control (with a small c), which enhances the readability
{
    if (control is PictureBox pictureBox) // As @EtiennedeMartel suggested, this is a neat and efficient way of achieving the desired. Use this please.
    {
        pictureBox.Image = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The second `if` is not necessary, because the `is` operator always evaluates to false for `null` values. Additionally, C# 6 allows to combine the check and the cast in one operation: `if(control is PictureBox pictureBox) ...`.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Beautiful. Thank you for giving this information. Can I modify the answer with your suggestion as it enhances the answer in a cleaner way?

Comment: Stack Overflow's content is open, go ahead.

Comment: You are right, the SO content is open, but updating my answer with your suggestion without asking your permission seemed unethical to me.

Comment: You should dispose the image first. `pictureBox.Image?.Dispose(); pictureBox.Image = null;`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [Controls.OfType<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.5.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) method so you get only PictureBoxes from the Form:

```
foreach(PictureBox pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
{
    pb.Image = null;
}
```